# replacing all String in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i have a dynamic string expression 
 var expression = "count+count1+12-(count3+count4)";

I want to append v[...] in each string like this output

**Output:-**

```
v[count]+v[count1]+12-(v[count3]+v[count4]);
```

i have tried this regex expression,

```
expression = expression.replace(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+/g, "v["/$1/"]").replace(/[\(|\|\.)]/g, "");
```

is it possible to write regex expression regex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```js
var expression = "count+count1+12-(count3+count4)";
var res = expression.replace(/\b[a-z]\w*/ig, "v[$&]");
console.log(res);
```

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

The replacement contains `$&`, a backreference to the whole match.

Another solution that splits with the math operators and only wraps with `v[...]` those substrings that are not a number or the operator:

```js
var expression = "count+count1+12+234.56-(count3+count4)";
var res = expression.split(/([-+\/*])/).map(function(x) {
   return /^(\d*\.?\d+|[-*\/+])$/.test(x) ? x : "v["+x+"]"; 
}).join("");
console.log(res);
```